# Creating Label for the application code in TFS using Nant script

Tags: perforce, nant, tfvc

Recently I migrated my code from Perforce to TFS. Earlier I was using the below nant script to create label for a particular version in the source control

```
<exec 
    program="p4" 
    commandline="label -t ${depot.template.label} AppName-${label.available.version}" 
/>
```

But now I want to use a modified script so that it works for TFS as well.

Has anybody faced a similar situation or if anybody is having any knowledge of it. Label can be created manually in VS but I want the command.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do from the commandline as well

```
 tf label labelname $/Project /Version:C12345 /recursive
```

To simply label latest, use:

```
 tf label labelname $/Project /Version:T /recursive
```

To simply label the workspace version, use:

```
 tf label labelname $/Project /Version:W /recursive
```

For full details, look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew32kd1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Instead of $/project you can also use `.` from the root directory of your TFS workspace.

The exec call for Nant takes the program `tf` and the arguments go in  he commandline attribute. I don't know what variables you have available to pass, but it would look like:

```
<exec 
    program="tf" 
    commandline="label '${LabelName}' $/Project /recursive"
/>
```

Make sure that `tf.exe` is in the search path. It by default lives in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jesse, but I want to use it in nant scripts so this syntax is not gonna work out. Can you suggest something in terms of Nant syntax which I have mentioned in the description.